# Subside or deflate

Tags: word-choice

I would like to ask if I can use the word deflate in the following context.

> It took seven days for the swelling to **subside** completely.

And is there a specific choice for swelling due to a bee sting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deflate comes from the latin word *deflare*, meaning to blow out. It gives the impression of air coming out, which probably isn't the image you want to convey for a bee sting.

Deflate has two other meanings (to make somebody lose confidence and to reduce the supply of money in the economy) but they are not really appropriate either.

I guess what you are looking for is an antonym for swell, but there isn't really anything better than subside.

There is no specific term for a bee sting, although there are medical terms for its consequences (inflammation, allergy, shock).

Answer (score 4):

I see what you're going for by using the word deflate, and it isn't necessarily incorrect, but it is essentially never used in this context and it would sound weird to the audience. Deflate is almost exclusively used to describe expulsion of air or gas from some expandable thing (e.g. a balloon). Because swelling is caused by an excess of blood, the use of deflate doesn't really work here. The most common alternatives to "subside" in the above example are probably "dissipate", "go down", or "go away".